# Jquery even odd selectors not working for dynamic content

Tags: jquery

After I change content by moving elements around, I want to re-apply `odd` and `even` styles for them. But in this specific example, it's not working. Unfortunately I can't use CSS for :even and :odd selectors (not supported in IE 8). Please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/rghg3j5v/

```
function highlightRows() {
    $('table tr:odd td').addClass('odd');
    $('table tr:even td').addClass('even');
}

highlightRows(); // Initial styling

$('.up').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var prev = $(parent).prev();

    $(parent).insertBefore(prev);
    highlightRows(); // Re-apply style when element is moved
});

$('.down').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var next = $(parent).next();

    $(parent).insertAfter(next);
    highlightRows(); // Re-apply style when element is moved
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to remove the old classes to reset, otherwise the elements end up with both classes, the first one taking presedence

```
function highlightRows() {
    $('table tr td').removeClass('odd even');
    $('table tr:odd td').addClass('odd');
    $('table tr:even td').addClass('even');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rghg3j5v/1/)

Comment: Stupid is as stupid does, we all do things like that from time to time.